# Strange colours in Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

About a week ago, Google Chrome on my Mac started looking like this:

[image]

What is going on? I have not installed any themes, so that would not be a possibility. I am running Google Chrome 5.0.307.1 dev

How can I revert Google Chrome back to how it is supposed to look?

Comment: I wonder if a recent update broke the Mac theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you picked up a theme somewhere. Try going to [the Google Chrome themes page](https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/google.html) and applying the Classic theme.

Comment: Makes no difference http://i.imgur.com/WleZx.png

Comment: Very odd. Have you tried reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

The menys on my website looks wired in the google chrome browser.

It ís like it doesn´t recognice the height and width, so they just makes the a-backgrounds as big as the text is.

To see the diffirence, look in the attached files.