# Odd Google Chrome behaviour

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

My Google Chrome has suddenly made the menu and all icons for itself stupidly bright. I can now hardly read my bookmarks or see most of the buttons.

Has anyone had anything similar happen to them? I've tried restarting my computer but nothing changed.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've installed a [theme](https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/index.html).

If you reset Chrome to the default skin does that restore the menu and icons?

Comment: Hmm, strange. I didn't have any other themes installed but what you suggested seems to of worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think an update must have been pushed out recently that has broken something. This seems to be happening a lot lately, ie [yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/103986/strange-colours-in-google-chrome), and also happened to me (exactly the same as yours). I didn't bother playing around or reading up, just switched to chrominium.

Answer (score 1):

Just to echo JT.WK, Chrome 4 was recently released and pushed out to people. This appears to have broken the current Chrome theme users have installed (possibly even the default one).

The simplest fix for it is to install your theme again or reset to default.